# how do i replace the lower case letters with upper case with the address of the string? in c

Tags: c, string, memory-address, uppercase

how to replace all lower case letters with upper case lettes with just the address of the string and not using functions from c libraries?

the changing to upper case is not the issue, it's this code

```
void upper_string(char s[]) {
   int c = 0;

   while (s[c] != '\0') {
      if (s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z') {
         s[c] = s[c] - 32;
      }
      c++;
   }
}
```

the problem is doing this without c functions from libraries and just knowing the address of the string.

Comment: What is the output of the program?

Comment: @LeeJenkins for eample.
for str="abra caDaBra"
output = "ABRA CADABRA"

but i don't even know what thestring is. i just know its address

Comment: @skidils I understand what you want the program to do. But what does it *actually* do? I assume you're asking this question because the program does not produce the correct results. What is it doing wrong?

Comment: So are you familiar with the difference between `char s[ ]` and `char* s`?

Comment: @LeeJenkins i'm asking because i'm stuck at this impass.i'm not sure what do with just the address of the string. i pretty much only have *var to work with. dont even know when the string ends

Comment: @LeeJenkins as far as i know. the first is an array, the seccond is a pointer. i am very new to c

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have right now? It doesn’t call any other functions, and it works using only an address.

Comment: @Ry- the problem is i don't know what to do with just the string adress. how do i know when the string ends? like. how do i handle the rest of the string

Comment: @skidils The code you have looks like it should work. The part you are missing is understanding the differences -- and similarities -- between `char s[ ]` and `char* s`. The explanation is a little too long for a comment here. See if this helps: https://www.dyclassroom.com/c/c-pointers-and-strings

Comment: @skidils: The string ends at `'\0'`. That’s what the code already checks for with `while (s[c] != '\0') {`.